# How can I transparently rewrite an old host url to a new host url?

Tags: apache

I have two apache virtual hosts within the same domain (and on same physical system):

```
old.example.com
new.example.com
```

I'd like to be able to transparently rewrite or map certain old url's to new. Example:
A request for http://old.example.com/foo would actually result in a request for http://new.example.com/foo

I want the http client (browser) to be unaware of the rewrite...in other words, I'm not looking to redirect. And, I only want to rewrite specific url's.

What can I add to either the virtual host or htaccess file(s) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html in the section titled *Dynamic Mirror*. I added this to my htaccess on http://old.example.com :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^foo http://new.example.com/foo [P]
```

The feature flag **P** tells the rule to use *Proxy Throughput*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could [set up your virtual hosts via mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/vhosts.html) and then simply add those rewriting steps to the configuration.

If, however, all you are trying to do is to re-use some things you have in the file system, without any magic in your config files, I would use symbolic links instead. (I have no idea if there are any equivalents for windows servers, though.)